# Getting error while install skype in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, skype

I'm getting error while installing Skype on Ubuntu 14.04 OS.

I've found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20190413/sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1) but solution not found. I have already installed MongoDB in my system.

**Error is like below:**

```
dpkg: error processing package flashplugin-installer (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see in your error, it's due to `flashplugin-installer` installation error. You can do as below to fix:

Completely remove `flashplugin-installer`:

```
sudo apt-get purge flashplugin-installer
```

If the error `Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)` persists while uninstalling `flashplugin-installer`, try this workaround:

1. Backup your `/var/lib/dpkg/status` 
   sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/status /var/lib/dpkg/status.orig
2. Edit `/var/lib/dpkg/status`: 
   sudo nano /var/lib/dpkg/status
3. Search for "flashplugin-nonfree" in the opened file.
   In nano you can press Ctrl-<kbd>W</kbd>, then type "flashplugin-nonfree" (without the quotes) and press Enter. The different entries are delimited by empty lines. Do not delete the first and best match you get. Keep searching (press Ctrl-<kbd>W</kbd>, then Enter again in nano) until you find a block (content between two empty lines) starting with:
   Package: flashplugin-nonfree
4. Delete this block.
   In nano, you can press Ctrl-<kbd>K</kbd> to delete single lines until the next package appears (you will recognize this by the empty line and another "Package: something" line)
5. Save the file
   In nano, Ctrl-<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>
6. Reboot your computer

Finally reinstall it

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

Comment: I'm getting same error while removing flashplugin

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: OK, I've updated my answer. Try it please.

Comment: I'm getting same error, See this<br/>

dpkg: error processing package update-notifier-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ttf-mscorefonts-installer:
 ttf-mscorefonts-installer depends on update-notifier-common (>= 0.119ubuntu2); however:
  Package update-notifier-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ttf-mscorefonts-installer (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Hum, this is a bug. I've updated my answer one more time. This should be the last resort solution.

Comment: Thanks for help
I  had both python 2.6 and 2.7 installed so I needed to switch back to 2.7 which had debian.deb822

**sudo update-alternatives --config python**

Comment: So you've found the solution?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33154/discussion-between-ketav-chotaliya-and-tung-tran).

Answer (score 0):

Try running;

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

to install any dependencies that made a the most recent .deb to install.

Comment: Getting error :  dpkg: error processing package ttf-mscorefonts-installer (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 update-notifier-common
 ttf-mscorefonts-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: run sudo apt-get install -f  again to install the dependancy for that also.