# How to install Skype from ".tar.gz" in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, skype

I need to know how I can install `skype-4.3.0.37.tar.bz2` in Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: The filename indicates that you're dealing with an archive. In a terminal type tar xvfj skype-4.3.0.37.tar.bz2 to unpack the archive to find out what it contains. Possibly it contains something you can install.

Comment: Why don't you use the Deb package like everybody else?

Comment: @DavidFoerster - It is absolutely not a duplicate. He doesn't want to install a `*.deb`, it's his choice.

Comment: @DavidFoerster - Maybe because of unknown errors such as this - http://askubuntu.com/questions/710758/getting-error-while-install-skype-in-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: @Raphael did you start reading minds?  Perhaps OP doesn't know there are deb files or how they can be used.

Comment: @muru - I said maybe. But he clearly stated that he wants to install a .tar.gz. How can we assume that he wants a .deb? Also, a quick google on how to install Skype in Ubuntu points to .deb. How, can he not know?

Comment: @Raphael you said it's absolutely not a dupe. If he has a tar.gz, of course he'll ask about installing a tar.gz. How do I know what he knows? I didn't claim to know what OP wants, you did.

Comment: @muru - I didn't assume that he wants a `.tar.gz`, he asked he wants a `.tar.gz`. And how come installing a .deb and installing a .tar.gz are dupes?

Comment: @Raphael where does the dupe question say anything about deb files?

Comment: @muru - It does : `wget download.skype.com/linux/skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb
sudo gdebi skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb`

Comment: @Raphael Here, you seem to be having some cognitive difficulties. Let me quote the entire question: "Skype 4.3 is just released with considerable improvements. As a regular Skype user I want to use the latest Skype on my Ubuntu 14.04, but there is no updates from Update Manager. Even in Skype website only Skype 4.3 is available only for Ubuntu 12.04. Is there anyway to use this latest Skype on Ubuntu 14.04 or how much we have to wait for the update?" Now, where in that is wget or deb files mentioned?

Comment: @muru - Oh! sorry about the Usr. LOL!

Comment: @muru - In the answer it only mentions *.deb! I am getting confused here.

Comment: @Raphael Generally, *questions* are duplicates. It's rare for answers to be considered. For example, you could post your answer there and then there would be no problem for you if this was closed, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the detailed steps as to how to install `Skype` from `tar.gz` in Ubuntu.

1. Download the `.tar.gz` from the website.
2. Now open file-manager and browse to the downloaded file.
3. Right-click on it and select `Extract Here`.

   [image: 1]

   [image: 2]
4. Browse to the extracted folder and open the README file:

   [image: 3]

   [image: 4]
5. Next, open a terminal and type (editing the relevant parts):

   ```
   cd DRAG AND DROP THE EXTRACTED skype-4.3.0* FOLDER HERE
   ```

[image: 5]

6. If you are in a 64-bit machine type the following command:

   ```
   sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
   ```
7. Type the following command:

   ```
   sudo cp skype /usr/bin
   ```

   [image: 6]
8. Next, type the following command:

   ```
   sudo mkdir /usr/share/skype
   ```

   [image: 7]
9. Next, type the following commands serially:

   ```
   sudo cp -R avatars/ /usr/share/skype/
   sudo cp -R sounds/ /usr/share/skype/
   sudo cp -R lang/ /usr/share/skype/
   ```

   [image: 8]
10. Now, close the terminal.
11. To launch Skype, type `skype` in the terminal.
12. If there are any errors, as shown in the screenshots then type the commands that follow:

    [image: 9]

    [image: 10]

    ```
    sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libqtdbus4:i386 libqtwebkit4:i386
    ```
13. Now, try to launch Skype again by typing `skype` in terminal. It should launch by now.

    [image: 11]

---

As requested by [jeykeu](https://askubuntu.com/users/22916/jeykeu), here are the scripts that automate the above process:

**Note**: Or you can download the scripts [for-installation](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=07075495873773949584) and [for-uninstallation](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=11574940489802164871).

- If required make it executable

  ```
  chmod +x /path/to/Skype-installation-ubuntu.sh

  chmod +x /path/to/Skype-uninstallation-ubuntu.sh
  ```

  then, double-click on it and click on `Run` to run the script.

**For installation**:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ~/Downloads/tmp
sleep 5
wget -c http://download.skype.com/linux/skype-4.3.0.37.tar.bz2
sleep 5
tar -xvzf skype-4.3.0.37.tar.bz2
sleep 5
cd skype*
sleep 5
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sleep 5
sudo cp skype /usr/bin
sleep 5
sudo mkdir /usr/share/skype
sleep 5
sudo cp -R avatars/ /usr/share/skype/
sleep 5
sudo cp -R sounds/ /usr/share/skype/
sleep 5
sudo cp -R lang/ /usr/share/skype/
sleep 5
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y libqtdbus4:i386 libqtwebkit4:i386
sleep 5
rm -rf ~/Downloads/tmp

exit 0
```

- Copy the above and save it as `/path/to/anyname.sh` also if required make it executable

  ```
  chmod +x /path/to/anyname.sh
  ```

  then, double-click on it and click on `Run` to run the script.

**For uninstallation**:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo rm -rf /usr/bin
sleep 5
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/skype
sleep 5
sudo apt-get remove --purge -y libqtdbus4:i386 libqtwebkit4:i386

exit 0
```

- Copy the above and save it as `/path/to/anyname.sh` also if required make it executable

  ```
  chmod +x /path/to/anyname.sh
  ```

  then, double-click on it and click on `Run` to run the script.

Comment: You could have created a shell script

Comment: @JeyKeu - Added

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal and navigate the directory where *skype-4.3.0.37.tar.bz2* is and run:

```
tar -xvjf skype-4.3.0.37.tar.bz2
```

Which will untar it to the current directory.Normally (99% of the time) it will create it's own subdirectory so you don't need to worry about that.
Just so you know:
`tar` - Tape ARchiver
And the options:
`x` - extract
`v` - verbose output (lists all files as they are extracted)
`j` - deal with bzipped file
`f` - read from a file, rather than a tape device

`tar --help` will give you more options and info.
From [how to extract a "tar.bz2" file?](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/how-to-extract-a-tar-bz2-file-161371).

To install run these two commands:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
dconf-editor
```

Expand **desktop**->**unity->panel** and add the following to the
    **systray-whitelist** item: 'Skype', 'skype' 
    Finally logout and login again from Unity. Navigate the *skype-4.3.0.37*  directory (where *skype-4.3.0.37.tar.bz2* initially was). Then do:

```
./skype
```

If the Skype  does not appear in the Tray, a workaround can be:

```
sudo apt-get install sni-qt:i386
```

From *skype-4.3.0.37* README.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Hossen works, but this procedure is deprecated (as in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Skype ).

The safest way to install skype is to run these commands on a terminal:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386

sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install skype
```

Skype is now installed and ready to use.