# can not install skype on ubuntu 15.10

Tags: apt, 15.10, skype

```
o@lifebook:~$ sudo apt-get install skype
[sudo] password for o: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 skype : Depends: skype-bin
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

i also tried apt-get install skype-bin skype 
but it is not working

```
 sudo apt-get install skype-bin skype
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 skype-bin:i386 : Depends: libqtwebkit4:i386 (>= 2.2~2011week36) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Try installing it from a [`.tar.gz`](http://askubuntu.com/questions/713734/how-to-install-skype-from-tar-gz-in-ubuntu-14-04) See if the error persists. Then you can try to install it from `.deb`

Comment: o@lifebook:~/Desktop/skype-4.3.0.37$ ./skype 
./skype: error while loading shared libraries: libQtWebKit.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
o@lifebook:~/Desktop/skype-4.3.0.37$ 
still not working

Comment: also i have installed sudo apt-get install  libQtWebKit*

Comment: The solution for that error is given in the above pointed answer.

Comment: Please type yhe conmands as given. Better copy the command and paste it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
528  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/ppa 
  529  sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ wily partner" >> \
  530  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list' 
  531  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa 
  532  sudo apt-key adv --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 5044912E
  533  sudo apt-get update 
  534  sudo apt-get install dro
  535  wget -q -O - http://archive.getdeb.net/getdeb-archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
  536  sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu wily-getdeb apps" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list'
  537  wget -q -O - http://archive.getdeb.net/getdeb-archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
  538  sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu wily-getdeb games" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list'
  539  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa 
  540  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ppa 
  541  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa 
  542  sudo apt-get update 
  543  sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ wily partner" >> \
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list' 
  544  sudo apt-get install skype
  545  sudo apt-get update 
  546  sudo apt-get history
  547  history
```

this is my history file. Fter adding some rep file **skype was installed and i dont know y ????but it works!!!!**
[skype 15.10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0w1Kb.png)

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

was used before

Comment: You repeat commands, do an `apt-get update` and the end, why? This no solve anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the for your Ubuntu http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/

Open Terminal,

Execute:

```
 sudo apt-get purge skype skype-bin
```

Or

First:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Then

```
sudo apt-get install skype
```

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 skype-bin:i386 : Depends: libqtwebkit4:i386 (>= 2.2~2011week36) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Try this.  _sudo apt-get remove --purge skype*_

Comment: no change stays same

Answer (score 0):

Skype is a 32 bits application, and you have a 64 bits install. Hence you need to tell your system to install 32 bits libraries when applicable. You can do that with this command:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

That should be sufficient to get rid of those "unmet dependencies" errors.

Comment: i have done it before but i did not changed situation. i guess main problem was in peros sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa 
  540  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ppa 
  541  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa 
  542  sudo apt-get update 
  543  sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ wily partner" >> \
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list' 
  544  sudo apt-get install skype

Comment: i dont know in which one of them has needed lib for skype (libqtwebkit igesss)

Comment: Those PPAs have nothing to do with it. But if I understand it correctly, you made it work, so then all is well, right?

Comment: yep :) thumbs up

Answer (score -3):

Skype for linux has not been updated since 12.04; It is most likely that the issue is, if you're using a ppa the dependencies needed are for 12.4 and apt-get is not retrieving the dependencies from the ppa, if you have installed g-debi it is better for you to go to [www.skype.com](http://www.skype.com) and just go to downloads and choose the deb they have for 12.4 (multiarch) that way you get all the dependencies from the deb, that's how I installed it on my end.

Comment: i  have not installed g-debi, and i have tried skype-debian_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb from skype.com but it still gives me error like "cannot install 'libqtwebkit4:i386' "

Comment: i have changed country settings and tried rebuild source.list from Ubuntu Sources List Generator (https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/)

Comment: canonical_partner.list                 noobslab-ubuntu-apps-wily.list
canonical_partner.list.save            noobslab-ubuntu-apps-wily.list.save
mutate-ubuntu-ppa-wily.list            xorg-edgers-ubuntu-ppa-wily.list
mutate-ubuntu-ppa-wily.list.save       xorg-edgers-ubuntu-ppa-wily.list.save
o@lifebook:~$ sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/

Comment: do not use the debian version choose ubuntu 12.4 also to install gdebi simply use sudo apt-get install gdebi, on a side note for skype the library libqtwebkit is not needed I don't even have it installed is it possible that your system is broken from an old attempt to install something else before if so try this http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=947124 last post to clean any held broken package

Comment: What you state about skype not having been updated since 12.04 is not correct. Admittedly the package name is confusing, but the version in the Canonical Partner repository is the latest available version.